# vue router can't delete query

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

i try to delete a query parameter with a button click.

For example my route is `http://localhost:8080/#/myroute?dialog=1`.
Now i click a button that should delete the query part `?dialog=1`.

My click function look like this:

```js
delete_query() {
  this.$router.replace({ query: null });
}
```

i have also try this attempts:

```js
delete_query() {
  this.$router.push({ query: null });
}

delete_query() {
  this.$router.push({ name: this.$route.name });
}
```

But all of these functions give me the same error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Redirected when going from "/myroute?dialog=1" to "/myroute" via a navigation guard.
```

Why?
What i do wrong? How can i solve this?

I have the actual version 3.5.1 of vue router installed.

Answer (score 0):

This Vue3 router option works.

```
router.push({ query: undefined})
```

TS: `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'LocationQueryRaw | undefined'`

Answer (score -1):

if i got it right, For delete a javascript object property you can use javascript's delete property. Like this.

```js
    delete_query() {
 delete this.$router.query // will delete all router queries 
 delete this.$router.query.name // will delete only name property.
}
```

Comment: Yes in an normal object that should work but not with vue router. I don't get an error but the query param not delete from the url.